# about Masjid al Aqsa

Tags: tafseer, history, masjid

In Quran it is said

> "Exalted is He who took His Servant by night from al-Masjid al-Haram to al-Masjid al- Aqsa, whose surroundings We have blessed, to show him of Our signs. Indeed, He is the Hearing, the Seeing."

But as much as I know Masjid al Aqsa was build in the regain of Umar (pbuh) and before there was a garbage dump. I know masjid means a place of prostration regardless of religion, but if there was a garbage dump then how can it be a place of prostration?
Can anyone please tell me about it?

Comment: Please share sources fro your claims. As for al-Masjid al-Aqsa it is a reference for the place of worship built by Suleyman () in the city known by then as Elya' arabized version for [Aelia Capitolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aelia_Capitolina) (see in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1397c) and [another version](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1397a), in which the Arabic name is quoted) or al-Bait al-Muqadas and now known as al-Quds or Jerusalem.

Comment: @Medi1Said OP is correct, when Umar went to Jerusalem, he met with Patriarch Sophronius who showed him temple mount and it was used as a garbage dump. Then Umar started and his army along with some Jews cleaned it up then built Masjid Al-Aqsa

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think I read this from 2 books,one of them is from seeing Islam as others saw it.But I think it's most of the muslims knows this story as I also heard this in my childhood. I don't know if jews participated in building it but I think if there was any jews they must be already accepted Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) as prophet of Allah and accepted Islam.So my question is Bait al Mukaddas  Masjid is real Mlasjid Al Aqsa that existed before?

Comment: @Medi1Saif sorry to bother you again but if the Baitul Mukaddas is real Masjid Al Aqsa mentioned in quran than what about the other Masjid that now known as al Aqsa Masjid which was built by Umar after he cleared the place of garbage dump?Is Baitul Mukaddas the real place from where Muhammad (pbuh) was taken to heaven( I mean Miraj) to meet with Allah.?

Comment: The mosque you are referring to was built by 'Abd al-Malik Ibn Marwaan it is much bigger than that built by Omar which was built around the rock and is now a small part of the mosque. Our prophet has taught us that the earth was made a masjid for him so no matter where a Muslim is he can pray he just needs to keep away from najasah and the garbage you are referring to was removed by Omar and the Muslims and the location was left to get three days of sunshine before they started building the mosque.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Well you can even search about it in internet,do you know about the story "Umar had went to visit the place of Al aqsa,at that time it was still a garbage dump, but he ordered people to make the place clear and in the way church to meet with it's patriarch and it was the time of prayer(Namaz), the Christian invited him to pray in Church but he refused saying If he pray here, in the future Muslims may snatch this church from Christian because Umar once prayed in the place."

Comment: @Medi1Saif then you can also read "seeing Islam as other saw it"I don't remember the page number.Though the story was very absurd in that book.The story was like that It say Jews cleared the place to build temple with the permission of Ismailities but they then indulge in wine, so the leader of the Ismailities got angry and jealous of the Jews and changed his mind so they were expelled form there,and Muslims started to pray there and as revenge Jews put some thing haram(some thing of pig, I don't exactly remember) in the door of prayer house.

Comment: @Medi1Saif But it can also be a flat lie and written with polemical intention as the writer was a Christian and criticized both religion.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Also I read a paper that was published by a anti Islamic author who really hate Islam, A J Deus and I don't recommend him at all.but what caught my eyes was one of his source,a very good source of early Islam.It's about a Christian Bishop or something noticed the garbage dump was cleaned by Arabs who invaded the place and complained that they and their leader were laughing and insulting Church or something like that and cleaned the place full of garbage and made the place for their prayer which the called Masjida

Comment: @Medi1Saif It can be that Umar first built a small Masjid there after cleaning the garbage dump, as the financial condition of Arabs at that time was not very good and they were busy in conquests and later Abd al-Malik Ibn Marwaan made the mosque bigger.